# Installing Sitecore9.2 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sitecore, sitecore9

Can anyone provide me answer to below query?

I wanted to install Sitecore9.2 on AWS, does the installation process requires SQL VMs?

or Can someone point me to right article to this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience Sitecore XM can use AWS RDS for the Database. If that is a good idea you must know yourself. For the installation, the Sitecore 9 installation uses contained database that may broke the SIF installation, you can turn it on in AWS RDS or use normal database user account but you need a workaround. like first installing on SQL server and migrate to RDS, or installing manual without SIF. or adjust SIF

For more information see:

https://jeroen-de-groot.com/2018/07/19/deploying-sitecore-9-in-aws-rds/

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11047/sitecore-9-installation-using-sql-active-directory-user/11063

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13859/why-do-we-require-contained-database-for-sitecore-9

https://sheenumalhi.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/sitecore-9-with-aws-rds/